# OSX Cocoa WebView sizeThatFits Equivalent

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, wkwebview

Heirarchy:

NSTableView -> NSTableCellView -> WebView

The `NSTableViewDelegate` returns the rendered height of the `webview` for `tableView:heightOfRow:`

The `NSTableCellView` is the `frameLoadDelegate`/`resourceLoadDelegate` for the `webview` and notifies the parent table to update the height for its row when the webview has finished rendering (`onFrameLoad:`)

For 95% of the rendered content, this works fine.

For specific webpages, the rendered height being returned is incorrect. I've tried using:

- `webview.mainFrame.DOMDocument.body.offsetHeight`
- `webview.mainFrame.DOMDocument.documentElement.boundingBox.size.height`
- appending an element to the end of body and using its client bounding rect

but neither of them give the correct height. This causes the table row to be of incorrect height as well and it seems like the page is being cropped unnecessarily. Any suggestions would be helpful!